# Open a text file passing path

Tags: c, shellexecute

I'v tried to use this code to open a text file in my program, but nothing is happening.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", filename, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Note that `system.start()` is not working either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to use ShellExecute() in C to open a .txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007537/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-shellexecute-in-c-to-open-a-txt)

Comment: Are you sure filename contains the full path to the file?  And what's the return value of this call?

Comment: yes. But, as suggested by @Barmar with that post, the path doesn't include double //. maybe thats the problem

Comment: if you need a literal \ in a C string you have to escape it, `"c:\testfile"` and `"c:\\testfile"` look totally different in code, and only the latter is correct.

Comment: well, i have used that same string with fopen and it works. should work here too as well dont it?

Comment: Not necessarily, eg fopen can find a file when you just give it a filename if the file happens to be in the current working directory it's running in, but ShellExecute won't.  Can you add the EXACT content of filename to your question?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging here.  For example, what's the return value from ShellExecute()?  Does it indicate success (read the API docs for ShellExecute) or a specific failure?

Comment: Check out what says return value of `ShellExecute()` and/or `GetLastError()` functions. Also,Where/how is `system.start()` defined?

Comment: i printed the output as an int and it returns 2, i dont know the meaning and neither doc explains it

Comment: well, it turned out to be an error in the syntax of execute shell. that post solved my problem. ty